# Firebase Analytics not showing screen names and events

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm migrating from old Google Analytics to Firebase Analytics and now I'm tracking the screens using this:

```
    mFirebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(SectionManager.getInstance().getCurrentActivity(), name, null /* class override */);
```

I also tried using this:

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, "screen");
    params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name);
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.VIEW_ITEM, params);
```

And I'm tracking events using this:

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("category", "command");
    params.putString("action", "test command");
    params.putString("label", "command test label");
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("ga_event", params);
```

I'm testing the application opening some screens and passing it's name, and also I'm pressing some times a button which executes the event tracking code I showed.

The first problem is that in Firebase panel, I can't find the "test command" event... Don't sure where should I find it, but I can't find it.

The second problem is that I can see the "screen class" of the activities I'm using for opening the screens, which represents the name of the activity, but the name of the screens I passed as a parameter to Firebase is not present. If I filter to show the screen name I got this:

```
User engagement   Screen name Screen name   % total     Avg. time   
(not set)   NaN -   0m 0s   -100
```

Comment: “firebase_”, “google_” and “ga_” prefixes are reserved and cannot be used. From the documentation

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the `setCurrentScreen()` event, you should be able to see it at the **Analytics > Events** panel. Then, select **screen_view** and a screen with, beyond other stuff, a card titled `firebase_screen` will show you the **sceen_view** events grouped by the name you gave them when logging the event.

Another card titled **User engagement** will show you the `screen_class` you want to see, as well as the visualization percentage and average time spent on each screen.

Custom events (like your `ga_event`) should also be shown at the **Analytics > Events** section at the Firebase Dashboard.

**Important:** Custom events might take [up to 24 hours](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en) after called to show up on Firebase.

Comment: you can track it during 60seconds: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7201382?hl=en&utm_id=ad&authuser=0