# Firebase Analytics - How to add Screen Names and Log Events

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

I want to add Screen Name and Log Event to Firebase's Analytics. I have tried below code, but I'm unable to see the Event & Screen Name in Firebase's Console.

```
//For Logging Event
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("custom_param",nameEditText.getText().toString());
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.GENERATE_LEAD, bundle);

//For Adding Screen Name
mFirebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(this, "Visitor Entry", VisitorEntryActivity.class.getSimpleName());
```

I have already added **Firebase SDK.** I don't know what exactly settings I need to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sometimes it takes time for events to appear in the Firebase console. Try adding multiple entries and wait for a while.

Comment: Or [mark your device as a debug device](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview), and switch to debug view in the console to check if your events are being logged correctly. If they are being logged in debug view, it's just a matter of time before they show up for other devices (as Iffat said).

Comment: Can we know how much time user took to enter data from specific widget? For example, while entering **Permanent Address**, We are having **EditText**. So any how can we know how much time user took to enter his/her address?@FrankvanPuffelen@IffatFatima

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Analytics not showing screen names and events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929566/firebase-analytics-not-showing-screen-names-and-events)

Answer (score 0):

Under MyActivity.java put

```
protected void onResume() {
    isActivityLive = true;
    super.onResume();
    analytics.setCurrentScreen(this, "Screen Name", this.getClass().getSimpleName());
}
```

Comment: Now Showing screen name in firebase analytics.